# Draw random image on a bubble image background like iMessage

Tags: ios

This is a chat app, the bubble is the background image, for text, i can just stretch the bubble image with "resizableImageWithCapInsets", and draw the text on the bubble.
But problem is when it is a random image, how can i draw the image on the bubble the way it is in the attached picture? both ios message and imessage on mac show the image in this way.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgJhv.png

Answer (score 0):

If your bubble is represented by a UIImageView (which is a subclass of UIView), you can add another UIImageView as a subview of your bubble. You would make the frame of this subview equal to the frame of your bubble, and then set the bubble's clipsToBounds property to YES, so the subview is constrained to the bubble.

You would then set the contentMode of the subview to UIViewContentModeAspectFill, which will strech the image to the size of your bubble. Something like this:

```
//After resizing the bubble to the size you want, to this:
bubbleView.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:bubbleView.frame];
imageView.image = theImage;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeAspectFill;
[bubbleView addSubview:imageView];'
[imageView release];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In this case, the imageView will cover the bubbleView, and stay rectangle shape. what i want is to use the image fill the bubble, which is a irregular shape.

Comment: When you set the clipsToBounds property to YES, the subview will be constrained to the shape of the bubbleView, giving you the effect you want.

Comment: All the shape of UIView is rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BubbleThingie](https://github.com/tkirby/BubbleThingie/blob/master/README.md) sample app. It does the image masking and gloss effect like in your example image.

[image]